# Is there a utility to indent C++ programs

Tags: c++, indentation

I am trying to use "indent" program to indent C++ programs. But it does not seem to work fine. It is messing up the indentation much more.

It is a Class file. Can you please suggest the right options for it or another program that works?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can give an example of what it's doing that you don't like and - more importantly - how you do want it to behave.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/):

> Artistic Style is a source code indenter, formatter, and beautifier for the C, C++, C# and Java programming languages.

Comment: That doesn't work.  It's only for Microsoft.

Comment: No it's not: "The Windows package contains a compiled binary. Other platforms will need to compile the source code. Makefiles are included for the most popular compilers"

Answer (score 12):

in visual studio, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> will auto-indent the entire file you're working in.

Answer (score 5):

Many editors like Vim and Emacs have a feature that reindents code according to its built-in indentation standard.

In Vim, you can type <kbd>=</kbd> with any motion. (Like <kbd>=%</kbd> at any block delimiter or <kbd>S-v</kbd> to select a region and then <kbd>=</kbd> to reformat.) The <kbd>gq</kbd> command can be used to reformat comments and other text.

In Emacs, you can type <kbd>M-x</kbd> `indent-region` after selecting a region. (Such as with <kbd>M-<</kbd> and <kbd>M-></kbd>.) You can also reformat comments with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `fill-paragraph`.

Comment: emacs:  Escape-x  indent-region.  (Select region first.)

Comment: and use `M-< C-space M->` to select the entirety of the current buffer...

Comment: Emacs can't do so called "complex indentation", i.e. make the braces to be hanging, or vice versa. [It's wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC) advices to use an external tools.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know this. Too bad that this doesn't fix the comment formatting though.

Answer (score 5):

Another tool for automated formatting of C++ code is [clang-format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html).

Answer (score 3):

http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/C-C++Beautifier-HOWTO.html

Answer (score 3):

This is in reply to the OP and other posters: I work under Windows and was looking for an indent as well. This is what I learned:

I tried *bcpp*. It seems to be quite old (more or less from 1996) and you need to find a windows exe. I found one here: http://www.zeusedit.com/zforum/viewtopic.php?t=1067. Still I think it's not really worth the bother, since it can only do space/tab, indentation level and brace conversion.

Then there is *Artistic Style*, which is newer and on sourceforge. It seems to be quite capable, but it can not, for example, reformat spaces around function names and parameters (like, turn `if ( a ( b ) )` into `if (a(b))`.

I like *Cygwin indent* ( http://www.cygwin.com/ ) best, but it works only well on newline separated files, so you have to use it like "dos2unix < infile | indent ...". But indent will not reformat boxed comments... :)

Maybe a combi of Artistic Style and Cygwin indent works best. Now I use this command line: `astyle --style=kr -s3 --break-closing-brackets < infile.cpp | dos2unix | indent --no-tabs --k-and-r-style --indent-level 3 --dont-cuddle-else | unix2dos`. I bit long, I agree, but apart from that it produces a very good result. :)

Comment: I believe *Artistic Style* **can** handle reformatting spaces nowadays with the `--unpad-paren` option.

Answer (score 2):

[bcpp](http://invisible-island.net/bcpp/bcpp.html), available in any linux distro (and probably for mingw/cygwin, but I have not checked it) is a C++ indenter and beautifier. You can parametrize how it works with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Another short key in Visual Studio 2008:

> **Ctrl+A, Alt+F8**

Comment: Doesn't work well with Qt code. in header files each signal, slot macro is indented one level more. The un-indentation is only done, when the next public/private/protected ocures.

Answer (score 0):

In **netbeans**, you can simply do

**Alt + Shift + F**

Please make sure that the plugins are installed for corresponding language. For example, for PHP code indentation, you have to choose netbeans PHP or install PHP plugins from repository.